# How to make a div object when clicked to do something

Tags: asp.net-core

I have 6 objects and here is an example of one of the objects:

```
<div class="item2"><div class="circle2"><img class="device2" src="Devices/mouse.png" alt="Mouse"></div></div>
```

and what I would like to do is when that object is clicked to pass a variable and activate a method in the backend and refresh the data on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch to retrieve data from the server (assuming you have a controller endpoint set up do do that). We would need a little more information as to where the variable is coming from and how you will use the data coming from the server trefine this answer.

```
<div class="item2" id="item2"><div class="circle2"><img class="device2" src="Devices/mouse.png" alt="Mouse"></div></div>
<script>
  const i2 = document.getElementById('item2')
  i2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let fetchUrl ="https://www.yourdomain.com/api?id=" + yourvariable;
    fetch(fetchUrl)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          //do something with data
        })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: It would be great if there is no javascript involved (as it is for a project) but the variable is used in a query in a WHERE statement (a string variable) so I believe it shouldnt be that complex. So I can filter between mouses, keyboards, headphones etc.